# How to position a DIV at specific coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html, coordinates

I want to position a DIV at specific coordinates, how can I do that using JavaScript?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Script its `left` and `top` properties as the number of pixels from the left edge and top edge respectively.  It must have `position: absolute;`

```
var d = document.getElementById('yourDivId');
d.style.position = "absolute";
d.style.left = x_pos+'px';
d.style.top = y_pos+'px';
```

Or do it as a function so you can attach it to an event like `onmousedown`

```
function placeDiv(x_pos, y_pos) {
  var d = document.getElementById('yourDivId');
  d.style.position = "absolute";
  d.style.left = x_pos+'px';
  d.style.top = y_pos+'px';
}
```

Comment: I retrieve the x,y coordinates from mouse click, how can I display the Div in the position of the mouse ?

Comment: @adham you already have the x,y coordinates?  Just apply them in place of `x_pos`,`y_pos`

Comment: it rounds the position always...is it possible to set position like 1.6 instead of it becoming 2 or 1.

Comment: what if we have cordinates, (x1,y2)(x2,y2)(x3,y3)(x4,y4) ?

Comment: I am doing the exact same thing but my div doesnt get positioned near the cordinate of my mouse. However it moves to the top starting position of the main page after the header. I mean the master Div. Can someone help me understand why?

Answer (score 43):

You don't have to use Javascript to do this.
Using plain-old css:

```
div.blah {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0; /*[wherever you want it]*/
  left:0; /*[wherever you want it]*/
}
```

If you feel you must use javascript, or are trying to do this dynamically
Using JQuery, this affects all divs of class "blah":

```
var blahclass =  $('.blah'); 
blahclass.css('position', 'absolute');
blahclass.css('top', 0); //or wherever you want it
blahclass.css('left', 0); //or wherever you want it
```

Alternatively, if you must use regular old-javascript you can grab by id

```
var domElement = document.getElementById('myElement');// don't go to to DOM every time you need it. Instead store in a variable and manipulate.
domElement.style.position = "absolute";
domElement.style.top = 0; //or whatever 
domElement.style.left = 0; // or whatever
```

Comment: what? you should use .class instead of myElement and top & left instead of x & y, should'nt you?

Comment: In addition to getting a reference to an HTML element with `document.getElemtentById()`, you can also reference it with an arbitrary jQuery-like selector with [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and its many variations

Comment: The requirement is to set from JavaScript so this answer doesn't help.

Answer (score 9):

well it depends if all you want is to position a div and then nothing else, you don't need to use java script for that. You can achieve this by CSS only. What matters is relative to what container you want to position your div, if you want to position it relative to document body then your div must be positioned absolute and its container must not be positioned relatively or absolutely, in that case your div will be positioned relative to the container.

Otherwise with Jquery if you want to position an element relative to document you can use offset() method.

```
$(".mydiv").offset({ top: 10, left: 30 });
```

if relative to offset parent position the parent relative or absolute. then use following...

```
var pos = $('.parent').offset();
var top = pos.top + 'no of pixel you want to give the mydiv from top relative to parent';
var left = pos.left + 'no of pixel you want to give the mydiv from left relative to parent';

$('.mydiv').css({
  position:'absolute',
  top:top,
  left:left
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a properly described article and also a sample with code.
[JS coordinates](http://javascript.info/tutorial/coordinates)

As per requirement. below is code which is posted at last in that article.
Need to call  **getOffset**  function and pass html element which returns its **top** and **left** values.

```
function getOffsetSum(elem) {
  var top=0, left=0
  while(elem) {
    top = top + parseInt(elem.offsetTop)
    left = left + parseInt(elem.offsetLeft)
    elem = elem.offsetParent        
  }

  return {top: top, left: left}
}


function getOffsetRect(elem) {
    var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect()

    var body = document.body
    var docElem = document.documentElement

    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop || body.scrollTop
    var scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft

    var clientTop = docElem.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0
    var clientLeft = docElem.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0

    var top  = box.top +  scrollTop - clientTop
    var left = box.left + scrollLeft - clientLeft

    return { top: Math.round(top), left: Math.round(left) }
}


function getOffset(elem) {
    if (elem.getBoundingClientRect) {
        return getOffsetRect(elem)
    } else {
        return getOffsetSum(elem)
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems complicated.

Answer (score 3):

To set the content of a div you can use the following:

```
   document.getElementById(id).style.top = "0px";
   document.getElementById(id).style.left = "0px";
```

Exists other good alternatives in jQuery

Answer (score 2):

You can also use position fixed css property.

```
<!-- html code --> 
<div class="box" id="myElement"></div>

/* css code */
.box {
    position: fixed;
}

// js code

document.getElementById('myElement').style.top = 0; //or whatever 
document.getElementById('myElement').style.left = 0; // or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

I cribbed this and added the 'px';
Works very well.

```
function getOffset(el) {
  el = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    left: (el.right + window.scrollX ) +'px',
    top: (el.top + window.scrollY ) +'px'
  }
}
to call: //Gets it to the right side
 el.style.top = getOffset(othis).top ; 
 el.style.left = getOffset(othis).left ;
```