# How to move this div left based on updated x position value?

Tags: javascript, css, position

http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/WvOmwL

[image]

This should be pretty simple, trying the answer [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802956/how-to-position-a-div-in-a-specific-coordinates) to no avail.

```
d.style.left = x_pos+'px';
```

I have a div `#carousel-list` I want to move left and right based on the < > nav buttons.

Current javascript:

```
document.getElementById('move-right').addEventListener("click", moveRight, false);

var carousel = document.getElementById("carousel-list");

function getPosX(el) {
  // yay readability
  for (var lx=0;
       el != null;
       lx += el.offsetLeft, el = el.offsetParent);
  return {x: lx};
}

function moveRight() {
  var currentX = getPosX(carousel);
  console.log(currentX.x); // returns 0
  console.log(currentX - 20); // returns NaN for some reason
  carousel.style.left = (currentX - 20)+'px';
  console.log(currentX.x); // still returns 0 so div does not move
}
```

Thoughts on my I can't move the `carousel` div? Or why `(currentX - 20)` returns `NaN` when `currentX` is the number `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, change:

```
carousel.style.left = (currentX - 20)+'px';
```

to:

```
carousel.style.left = (currentX.x - 20)+'px';
```