# How set obj coordinate in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var firstBut = document.createElement("button");
    firstBut.id="firstBut";
    firstBut.top=500;
    firstBut.left=500;
    firstBut.textContent="Нажми меня"
    document.body.appendChild(firstBut);
```

I want to set specific coordinate for elements. 
I dont find any variant how to do this?
Can you help me pls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to position a DIV in a specific coordinates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802956/how-to-position-a-div-in-a-specific-coordinates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```js
var firstBut = document.createElement("button");
firstBut.id = "firstBut";
firstBut.style.position = 'absolute';
firstBut.style.top = '500px';
firstBut.style.left = '500px';
firstBut.textContent = "Нажми меня"
document.body.appendChild(firstBut);
```