# X and Y positioning with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is a simple practice code where I want to position the box via X and Y coordinates. After viewing my code what would be the best and most cutting edge way to do this simple task?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    
</script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
#economy{
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    
}
</style>
</head>

<header>
</header>
    
<body>
    <div id="economy"></div>
</body>

<footer>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: you want him to move or just be positioned?

Comment: aside from margin and padding

Comment: positioned, preferrably using percentages

Comment: Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802956/how-to-position-a-div-in-a-specific-coordinates

Comment: Thank you, DanyCode and @Skywalker

Comment: Still am new to scripts but will take that suggestion and work on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to position a DIV in a specific coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802956/how-to-position-a-div-in-a-specific-coordinates)