# Place a horizontal rule in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that is used to display the users data.

This div is used to simulate how the users data will be printed. The users printed data can be 1 or many pages long.

I am trying to simulate a page break on the div each time the height of the div reaches the height of 3507px.

I have searched SO & google to find a solution, but I am stumped. I am unsure if this can be accomplished using CSS or jQuery.

How do I display a [horizontal rule](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp) or some other such line break indicator in the div (to indicate a page break) each time the height of the div reaches the height of 3507px?

Here is the HTML code of my div:

```
<div style="border: 2px dashed red;">
    <div id="live_preview" class="livePreview_resumeWrapper2"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.livePreview_resumeWrapper2 {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0 #888;
    direction: ltr;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%
}
```

I will appreciate any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: What happens to the content when it grows beyond div max-height? Is it hidden or does it spill into the following div? Adding more detail to your question would be helpful.

Comment: Roberto - it should spill into the next / following div. If I can supply you with more information, I will. What other information would you like?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802956/how-to-position-a-div-in-a-specific-coordinates could help you find a way

Answer (score 0):

the idea that occures to me is:

1)Get the height of the page

var page_height = $('.page').height();

2)Get the count of the hr you would require

var hr_count = Math.floor(page_height / 3507);

3)Set the page as relative

.page{ position: relative}

4)Now knowing the count of the hr you need to display append them to the page with an absolute position;

```
for(i=1; i<=hr_count; ++i){
   $('.page').append('<hr style="position: absolute; top: ' + i * 3507 + 'px;"');}
```

The only issue I see is that the hr may appear straight on top of a text, but at least you would know that there goes a line break.

why 3507px?
What if somebody changes the margins of they print setup, or uses different type of paper like a4, a3, letter?

Best regards