# How to place a button over a image in a position specifically(x, y) with Javascript/AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a project using angularJS, in my project I have 2 images:

```html
Image 1: <br/>

<img src="http://www.google.com/favicon.ico" alt="" ng-click="mark($event)" width="100"/>

<hr/>

Image 2: <br/>

<img src="http://www.google.com/favicon.ico" alt="" width="100"/>
```

When the user click in Image 1 I capture position x, y of image.

```
$scope.mark= function(event){
    console.log("x = " + event.offsetX);
    console.log("y = " + event.offsetY);
}
```

Getting some like:

```
x = 123
y = 12
```

I need put a button over image 2 in the position (x, y) of the image 1 with angularjs/javascript, where user clicked (Image 1).

Both images are same.

I was investigating but not found a solution using just angularjs or javascript.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to position a DIV in a specific coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802956/how-to-position-a-div-in-a-specific-coordinates)

Comment: This solution position the div related to the document, but i need that position related to the image.

Comment: You can't do it relative to an image (since it's not a container). Wrap the image in a `<div style="position: relative">` and add the button to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle was already suggested by @Eddy Howard. You could put the functionality into a directive for convenience, something like this maybe (although it is not the optimal solution):

```
.directive('posButton', function() {
   return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      onClick: '=onClick',
      position: '=pos'
    },
    template: '<button ng-click="onClick()">foo</button>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

     element.css({
       visibility: 'hidden',
       position: 'absolute',
       top: '0px',
       left: '0px'
      });

      scope.$watch('position', function(){
        if(scope.position.length > 0) move(scope.position);
      }, true);

      function move(pos){
        element.css({
          visibility: 'visible',
          left:  pos[0] + 'px',
          top: pos[1] + 'px'
        });
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Here is a working [plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/plunk/bM5SHKpQJBKNcyVx).

Answer (score 1):

For positioning I use this in javascript:

```
<img src="http://www.google.com/favicon.ico" alt="" ng-click="mark($event)" 
    style="position: absolute; width: 50%; left: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px;"/>
```

That will always make the object appear on the left hand of the page. You add this to your other image:

```
style="position: absolute; width: 25%; left: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 50%;"
```

And that should put your other image on top at half the width and height.

Hope that's what your looking for. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

On click event / function of image 1, set the position variables, then tie another elements position to those variables using ng-style 
(You can also use an ng-show on the 2nd element and set that as true on the img1 click function to hide/show the element only after clicking)

```
<!-- this is the image that will show after clicking img 1 -->
<img src="http://www.google.com/favicon.ico" width="100"
     ng-show="$scope.clickedImg1" style="position: absolute; width: 50%;"
     ng-style="{'left': $scope.posx, 'top': $scope.posy}"/>
```

Something of that nature anyways, this will allow you to dynamically move the element around by changing "posx" and "posy" variables.

posx and posy should be set as string like so:

```
$scope.posx = someXInt + 'px';
$scope.posy = someYint + 'px';
```