# position this element I created with JavaScript Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

### CODE

```js
function createButton(){
    var newEl = document.createElement("header");
    var r = document.createTextNode("My Chrome Extension");
    newEl.appendChild(r);
    document.body.appendChild(newEl);
}

createButton();
```

So I just learned how to create an element in JavaScript but the element spawns at the bottom left corner of the screen so how do I position it???

Comment: **How** do you want to position it? Are you familiar with CSS's visual-formatting model? `ResizeObserver`? absolute vs. static positioning? Remember that in general HTML elements are laid-out in a "flow"-model (i.e. they don't actually have "a position": their location in the document depends on other elements).

Comment: css is the way to go, you'll have to do `newEl.style.property` before `newEl.appendChild(r)`, reference : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar I saw the reference and it shows color changing, mind showing an example of position changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move your elements around using it's css properties :

[How to position a DIV in a specific coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802956/how-to-position-a-div-in-a-specific-coordinates)