# Pop up on hover <area> tag, HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm mapping some coordinates on an image map and I want to display a pop-up message, containing a description and an image on hover, but I can't figure out how to do it. I tried to contain the area in a `div` like this:

EDIT. I changed the HTML and CSS like this:

```html
<div class="contain">
    <area target="" alt="Agri-Eco Park Gate" title="Agri-Eco Park Gate" href="" coords="836,449,793,414" shape="rect">
    <div class="content">
        <h2>fasdasd</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam, non dolorum.</p>
        <img src="image.jpg" alt="image" onmouseover="popUp()">
    </div>
</div>
```

And style like this:

```css
.contain{        
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.contain .area {       
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #777;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.contain .area .content{    
    position: relative;
    bottom: 55px;
    width: 400px;
    background: white;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform: translateX(-50px) translateY(-50px);
}

.contain .area:hover .content{      
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(-50px) translateY();
}
```

What I want is to display the [pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENSGc.png) like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utWuJ.png) on the coordinate on this image [map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ooehj.jpg). I used this plug in to highlight the areas in the [map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvXMq.png).

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.maphilight.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('.map').maphilight();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside of your `<img>` tag, add an `onmouseover` event. Then we can create a function inside of a `<script>` tag (preferable in your head element) that displays the alert. The code should look something like this.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image" onmouseover="popUp()">

// JavaScript
function popUp() {
alert("put whatever text here");
}
```

`alert()` can be very intrusive if used frequently and can only contain text. If you want an image to display, you will have to put some more work in. Check out this resource for Modal images:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp 
And for more about `alert()` and `onmouseover`:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and useful links @nebula49dev! After some reading I kind of grasp what should I do but I'm still a little confused. When I hover the area at the map, how should I get the pop-up like on the images that I provided above? The content is stuck [here](https://imgur.com/a/dlLYAkd) . Is it possible to use the `onmouseover` on the `<area>` tag? Can you give an example?

Comment: I have never had this issue before, but after some looking around I saw this resource. I would recommend you create a div with its own class for every popup you want, and style them in CSS. If you want the rounded edges, add "border-radius." Then you can stack it on top of the map using this resource: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div-using-css.php

Comment: Thanks a lot, @nebula49dev! I can now stack an item on the image map, but it is not in the position or the are coords. Is it possible place this `<div>` in the same spot as the area coordinates?

Comment: When I was researching this question, I found out somebody asked the same one on this very site and got an answer. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802956/how-to-position-a-div-in-a-specific-coordinates

Comment: Update. I did something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/68kgcp2L/) and the result is [this](https://imgur.com/a/hG2Gmab). Is set the z-index of ` img class="map"` to 0 and the `calss="container"` to 1 but it did not stack up

Comment: Not sure if you saw it, so I'm sending another comment. Check this out, someone asked the same question on this site. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802956/how-to-position-a-div-in-a-specific-coordinates